# http basic authentication using spring security 3

Tags: security, spring-mvc, spring-security, directory, http-authentication

I am trying to secure a folder using http-basic authentication.

I have a folder 'files' in my web content containing some files.
I want to view its contents in the form of directory listing.

web.xml:

```
  <!-- definition for the default servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>convex</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>convex</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ConvexUpdate</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Add a mapping for our new default servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ConvexUpdate</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/files</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/convex-*.xml,
            /WEB-INF/convex-database.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
                </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

convex-security.xml

```
  <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

 <security:http auto-config="true" >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/files*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:http-basic></security:http-basic>
    </security:http>
```

Controller Snippet:

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RequestMapping(value="files.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getFiles(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/files/");  
        //files is the url-pattern of the second servlet  

        rd.forward(request, response);//method may be include or forward  

    }
```

However When i enter the url:-
http://localhost:8080/ConvexUpdateSite/files/

It is not asking for authentication and files are being listed.

however it is asking authentication if i remove the leading "/":
http://localhost:8080/ConvexUpdateSite/

Comment: why did you add to your web.xml a "special" servlet mapping for /files? try to remove it and see if it works.

Comment: i added a special servlet mapping for /files

Comment: I added this to override the default directory listing from false in apache/conf/web.xml  to true for my particular servlet /files
       

    <!-- Add a mapping for our new default servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ConvexUpdate</servlet-name> <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <url-pattern>/files</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
   <listener>

Comment: what is the recommended place to place the folder "files" WEB-INF or WebContent ?

Comment: you do not need special servlet for /files, as Spring handles it.